# sharepoint training

Tags: training

I've been developing with sharepoint for over a year now. any training out there that anyone would recommend to get to a more advanced level?
thanks

Answer (score 4):

I haven't taken the training myself, but some SharePoint consultants I work with highly recommended Critical Path Training: http://www.criticalpathtraining.com/Pages/default.aspx

The company is a joint venture between Ted Pattison and Andrew Connell, who have written several popular SharePoint books.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach to formal training is to study for the certifications. In the process of working through the certification requirements, writing code samples, reading MSDN, etc. I think you'll hit a lot of areas where you've never had any exposure and you'll probably learn a lot.

Practice tests from vendors like [MeasureUp](http://www.measureup.com/) can also help you gauge your skills.

Comment: Yes, the MCTS 70-573 exam (SharePoint 2010, Application Development
) should be your first step.

Comment: I know in having spent a little bit of time looking at 70-573 I've learned a lot about areas I didn't have hands-on experience with.

Answer (score 2):

I'm definitely biased because I'm on the faculty, but I believe that USPJ Academy is a great way to learn and also quite affordable.

In fact, just today we are announcing that we are offering single courses for purchase if you'd like to give it a try.

Edit: Mod removed link as it looks USPJA is no more.

Answer (score 2):

+1 to SharePoint Wrangler's suggestion about Critical Path Training.

I'd also suggest the [Microsoft Virtual Academy](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/Studies/SearchResult.aspx?q=sharepoint) and [Pluralsight](http://www.pluralsight.com/search/?searchTerm=sharepoint)

Comment: You might want to disclose you have content on Pluralsight Rob

Comment: I have content on Pluralsight.